# Improving throughput of CFU plating?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, lab-techniques, measurement

In a [separate question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/13518/alternatives-to-cfu-plating-for-measuring-number-of-viable-cells) I've described my general experimental setup where I need to measure the number of live cells in a growing bacterial culture in a fairly rapid and high-throughput manner. In that question I'm asking if there are any alternatives to the gold standard of CFU plating for making this measurement. As I wrote that question, it occurred to me that if I could just make CFU plating easier to do with lots of samples (esp. using fewer plates), then this method could work just as well. So my question here is if there is a way to make CFU serial dilution plating easier when I have to measure the number of live cells in 7+ different growth conditions every hour of growth?

Thanks!

Comment: see [my answer](http://biology.stackexchange.com/a/13522/948) on your previous question - I'm not sure you'll be able to get much more high-throughput than that :)

Comment: Thanks, @MattDMo. I agree that the Cedex machine is more high-throughput, but I am looking for any neat tricks people have tried to make CFU plating more economical. For example, one idea would be to put agar in each well of a [12 well plate][1] and do 12 samples at a time; then the question would be if people have tried this and the reduction in available area for counting made the CFU counting significantly less reliable. Or something like that. [1]:http://globebio.com/plates/multiwell-plates/suspension-culture-sterile-multiwell-plates/12-well-cell-culture-plate-with-lid-sterile.html